# java print in colour in text file

Tags: java, printing, output, readfile

hi there I have a Java program I wanna know how to print the result of this program in a text file without losing it's colour .I mean the out put is in colour and I want to have the colourfull printed result Thanks

Comment: which text file has colour in it?

Comment: anything but plain text file but I only know how to get the result in plain text file  :(

Comment: @UmaKanth he probably wants to the text file look like his IDE console.

Comment: exactly @PhilippSander thanks :)

Comment: a text file doesn't have color information nor any other formatting information in it.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't.**

Plain text is just that. There is no formatting in a plain text file that lets you specify color/font/size.

However, if you are displaying the text in a Bash shell or have configured your windows command console correctly, you could use ANSI Escape Codes to format the text.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't. Textfiles don't have colors.**

You could wrap them in HTML tags and style them with css. (there are probably libaries that do that for you). This HTML file can be viewed with a webbrowser.

You could also use [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to format your text (e.g. https://github.com/fusesource/jansi)